# ORA-01858 when using function TO_DATE

Tags: sql, oracle, date

```
select * 
from GM_STANDARD_UPLOAD_TEMP t
where  
    to_Date('24-DEC-2017') >  to_date(T.COL34) 
    and T.COL34 IS NOT NULL
    AND UPLOAD_BATCH_ID = 'UH00002319122018025335' 
    AND USER_AID = 'US000000' 
    and T.record_no > 1 
    and T.TRANS_TYPE='ADD';
```

Here my `t.col34` value is coming from table where column datatype is `varchar2(20)`. 
I tried to compare this to values but some time I got the following error:

> ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was
>   expected

Comment: Why on earth are you storing DATE values in a `varchar` column. That is a really bad idea. The error indicates that your column does not contain valid date values

Answer (score 6):

You are not using `to_date` correctly. This Oracle function expects a second argument, that specifies the format of the given input string.

```
to_Date('24-DEC-2017')
```

Should be written as :

```
to_Date('24-DEC-2017', 'dd-mmm-yyyy')
```

Or :

```
to_Date('24-DEC-2017', 'dd-mon-yyyy', 'nls_date_language = american')
```

Same goes for column T34, which you said is a VARCHAR2. You need to specify in which format string dates are stored in this column. Assuming that this is the same format as `'24-DEC-2017'`, you want :

```
 to_Date('24-DEC-2017', 'dd-mmm-yyyy') >  to_date(T.COL34, 'dd-mmm-yyyy')
```

See [the Oracle Datetime Format Models](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34924) for more details.

PS : please note that storing dates in a VARCHAR column is a bad practice and should be avoided (error prone, not efficient, ...). Oracle provides the DATE data type that is meant for that use case (along with various other related date data types).

Comment: Actually it should be written as `to_Date('24-DEC-2017', 'dd-mon-yyyy', 'nls_date_language = american')` or `to_Date('24-12-2017', 'dd-mm-yyyy')`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit : thanks for the comment, updated my answer accordingly